# Figure out an XPath that is useful in Robot Framework

Tags: html, xpath, robotframework

I need to access the first cell of something that looks like a table (but is slightly weird - the DIV for the first column is structurally "above" the rest of the cells on the same row).

```
<div class="slick-viewport slick-viewport-top slick-viewport-left" tabindex="0" hidefocus="" style="overflow: auto; width: 100%; height: 513px;">
   <div class="grid-canvas grid-canvas-top grid-canvas-left" tabindex="0" hidefocus="" style="height: 825px; width: 1336px;" unselectable="on">
      <div class="ui-widget-content slick-row  even lastClicked selected" role="row" row="0" style="top:0px;">
         <div class="slick-cell l0 r0  uppercase selected" aria-describedby="inforDataGrid160360C1" tabindex="-1" role="gridcell"><span style="float: left;display:inline-block;height:1px;width:0px"></span><button type="button" class="tree-expand inforIconButton  closed"><span></span></button><span>ABC</span></div>
         <div class="slick-cell l1 r1  uppercase selected" aria-describedby="inforDataGrid160360C2" tabindex="-1" role="gridcell">DEF</div>
         <div class="slick-cell l2 r2  uppercase selected" aria-describedby="inforDataGrid160360C3" tabindex="-1" role="gridcell">GHI</div>
      </div>
      <div class="ui-widget-content slick-row  odd" role="row" row="1" style="top:25px;">
         <div class="slick-cell l0 r0  uppercase" aria-describedby="inforDataGrid160360C1" tabindex="-1" role="gridcell"><span style="float: left;display:inline-block;height:1px;width:0px"></span><button type="button" class="tree-expand inforIconButton  closed"><span></span></button><span>JKL</span></div>
```

I am looking for something useful that points out ABC. As one can see the div above that has the property `row="0"` which seems reasonable to use. The div with ABC in has the class `l0 r0` which also seems useful (but what is slightly counter intuitive is that the class of the next cell on the same line - containing DEF - is  not `l0 r1` or `l1 r0` or something like that but instead `l1 r1`).

Also, many DIV levels up there is an `id="contentBody"` that I would like to include.

So something like `//contentBody/*/row="0"/class="l0 r0"`.

How do I construct this XPath?

(DEF is the second cell/column on the first line, GHI is the third cell/column on the first line. JKL is the first cell/column on the second line. I included this for you to get an idea of how this table is constructed).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This one should return required `div`:

```
//div[@id="contentBody"]//div[@row="0"]/div[contains(@class, "l0") and contains(@class, "r0")]
```

The same in CSS-selector:

```
div#contentBody div[row="0"]>div.l0.r0
```

You can use [selectors cheat-sheet](http://www.cheat-sheets.org/saved-copy/Locators_table_1_0_2.pdf) for creating XPath/CSS selectors as well as [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp), [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath) for deep understanding

Comment: Weirdly enough, the CSS-version didn't work in Selenium. It worked fine in Chrome's web inspector but Robot Framework reported an error (couldn't find the element). Do you know why?

Comment: @d-b , try to add spaces around `>`: `div#contentBody div[row="0"] > div.l0.r0`. Spaces are optional actually, but some tools might behave differently with and without them